# Get the variable name based on the methods that it was called from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHello() {
        // get the name of the class here which is defined as bar
        console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`)
    }
}

var bar = new Foo("John");
bar.sayHello();
```

Here, as you can see there is a defined class called `Foo` and it has a method associated with it called, `sayHello`. So, when I called this method, like `bar.sayHello();`, how can I get the access to the variable name which is `bar`. I know that `bar.constructor.name` would return me Foo as the name, but I am looking for the way to get the name bar. How can I do it in JavaScript.

Thank You.

Comment: There are one or two hacks that could be done to achieve this, but it's *very* strange - there should be absolutely no need to do this. A script should never depend on its variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't allow variable names to be accessed. You simply cannot get the variable name from the actual value of the variable in a reliable manner, nor should you have to in the first place. However, if you really need to for some inexplicable reason, and you're using browser javascript, you can just scan the window object (note that this will only work if your variable isn't a primitive).

```js
function getVarName(variable) {
    for (let key in window) {
        if (window[key] == variable) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
var var1 = {};
foobar = {};
let var2 = {};
const var3 = {};
console.log(getVarName(var1)); // var1
console.log(getVarName(foobar)); // foobar
console.log(getVarName(var2)); // null
console.log(getVarName(var3)); //null
```

Note how the last two don't work because this is hack that is in no way guaranteed to work.

**EDIT:** This also works in node if you use `global` instead of `window`, but the last two examples I demonstrated still won't work.

Comment: I want to use it like:

var x = new MyClass()
x.MyExtensionMethod()

and,
MyExtensionMethod()
{
    //get the name "x" somehow
}
Is It Possible?